# Does WordPress only support HTTP 1.1?

Tags: http

I'm not sure if this is a bug or if I'm missing anything. But according to the documentation for [WP_Http::request()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_http/request/), you should be able to set the HTTP protocol version with the `httpversion` option.

Indeed it seems to default to 1.0 according to line 181 of class-http.php:

```php
            'httpversion'         => apply_filters( 'http_request_version', '1.0', $url ),
```

But that value isn't actually passed down to [Requests::request()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/requests/request/). That method gets its default options from [Requests::get_default_options()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/requests/get_default_options/), which has an option, `protocol_version`, which defaults to 1.1.

It never actually reads httpversion, nor is httpversion even passed in the options.

All the transports then seem to read the protocol_version option, which is never configurable as far as I can tell.

So my question is, is this a bug or am I just missing something? Setting `httpversion` doesn't actually seem to accomplish anything, and you can't actually set `protocol_version`.

Comment: I'm looking through the code and I think this is indeed a bug. When the `Requests` library was introduced it looks like the `httpversion` argument was left behind, even though it no longer did anything: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/commit/37f6e6813a7def737797768a15da43d9067523c3 Probably worth reporting: https://make.wordpress.org/core/reports/

Comment: Thanks! I've created a bug [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/53513).